# only one field not working, sql syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

iv'e created a database in mySQL with the following as mentioned in the code :

```
<?php

// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("myURL","myUSER","myPassword","NewActivities");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }



$sql="INSERT INTO NewActivities1 (address, title, description, area, category, frequency, when)
VALUES
('$_POST[address]','$_POST[title]','$_POST[description]','$_POST[area]','$_POST[category]','$_POST[frequency]','$_POST[when]')";
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo "1 record added";
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

i keep getting this error: 
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'when) VALUES('fff','fff','fff','Stockholm','Activities','One time','fff')' at line 1

if i removed the "when" from the query the database gets updated in the mentioned fields.

the field "when" in the form is defined with the attribute "name="when""

what may seem to be the problem?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WHEN` is a [Reserved Word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/reserved-words.html).  As documented under [Schema Object Names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/identifiers.html):

> If an identifier contains special characters or is a reserved word, you *must* quote it whenever you refer to it. (Exception: A reserved word that follows a period in a qualified name must be an identifier, so it need not be quoted.)
>
> ```
> [ deletia ]
> ```
>
> The identifier quote character is the backtick (“`` ` ``”):
>
> ```sql
> mysql> SELECT * FROM `select` WHERE `select`.id > 100;
> ```
>
> If the [`ANSI_QUOTES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes) SQL mode is enabled, it is also permissible to quote identifiers within double quotation marks:
>
> ```sql
> mysql> CREATE TABLE "test" (col INT);
> ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax...
> mysql> SET sql_mode='ANSI_QUOTES';
> mysql> CREATE TABLE "test" (col INT);
> Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
> ```

Therefore:

```php
$sql="INSERT INTO NewActivities1 (address, title, description, area, category, frequency, `when`)
```

You also really ought to read up on proper string escaping (and how failure to do so exposes your application both to bugs and commonly exploited attack vectors):  I thoroughly recommend @[deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze)'s blog article, [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism).

In particular, as he describes in his article, concatenating unescaped strings supplied by the user directly into your SQL not only makes you vulnerable to [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com), but furthermore introduces bugs where the strings contain characters that have special meaning within SQL string literals (for example `'`).

[**The** solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496) is to *prepare* SQL statements with *placeholders* for parameters that get substituted with your variables upon command execution.

Comment: Better answer than mine for sure.. +1

Comment: thank you so much guys ! that was indeed the problem, i guess each day you learn something new :)